# Update when value is updated rather that when a key is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So, I was thinking about a question I asked a little while ago about how using `keyUp` could usually detect when a key was pressed. However, the problem with that method is that should you hold down a key (logically it would probably be backspace that you would hold down), it updates *after* the key is up which means *after they pressed* it.

I feel like this could be problematic if you would want something to update every time the `input` got longer or shorter.

Any ideas on how you could fix this problem? My idea is something that constantly checks if the `.length;` has changed but even if that did work, I don't know how you could do it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you looked into `onChange`?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/change/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `onChange` , or jquery way

```
$(document).on('change','#yourinput',function(){  
console.log($(this).val)
})
```